# RegisterInstance & TransientLifetimeManager, is it even possible?

Tags: c#, unity-container

Recently one of our development teams started with dependency injection.

One thing I noticed is that (when initializing the Container) the code has a lot of places, where it uses a `TransientLifetimeManager` on a instance. The instance has been created explicitly by the developer a few lines before.

```
KalenderView kalenderView = new KalenderView(new KalenderViewModel());
unityContainer.RegisterInstance(kalenderView, new TransientLifetimeManager());
```

Personally I would rewrite it into two RegisterType calls, one for the ViewModel, one for the View, but this got my attention.

My question is: Will the code even do, what I would expect it to do?
It looks like it's creating a new object everytime a instance needs to be resolved (roughly explained). But that can't be right, can it? It would be "magic" for me, I don't think, unity can "analyse" and save the state of an object during registration, right?

I found nothing on whether it's possible to use TransientLifetimeManager on RegisterInstance. So, will it ignore the given manager and use the ContainerControlledLifetimeManager instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's write simple test:

```
namespace UnityTest
{
    using System;
    using Unity;

    class Program
    {
        public class TestClass
        {
            public static int Version = 0;

            public TestClass()
            {
                Version++;
                Console.WriteLine(Version);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();

            var obj = new TestClass();

            container.RegisterInstance(obj, new TransientLifetimeManager());

            container.Resolve<TestClass>();
            container.Resolve<TestClass>();
            container.Resolve<TestClass>();
        }
    }
}
```

Will output:

```
1
2
3
4
```

So, container creates new instance per resolve.

You can even remove registration and it will work:

```
namespace UnityTest
{
    using System;
    using Unity;

    class Program
    {
        public class TestClass
        {
            public static int Version = 0;

            public TestClass()
            {
                Version++;
                Console.WriteLine(Version);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();

            container.Resolve<TestClass>();
            container.Resolve<TestClass>();
            container.Resolve<TestClass>();
        }
    }
}
```

Will output:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: I dont know, how unity does it, but this answers my question indirectly :)

Comment: @Jannik unity just ignores your instance and creates new one per resolve

Comment: So, that would mean, if I add a thing to my constructor that isn't known to unity, e.g. IUnknownInterface, that would not work right?

Comment: @Jannik for interfaces - yes, unity can not construct object of unknown interface type, but it can build up any non abstract class